# XBee packet format

Tags: xbee

I have to [IEEE 802.15.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4) devices running. The question is about [XBee-PRO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee).

```
Firmware: XBEE PRO 802.15.4 (Version: 10e6)
Hardware: XBEE (Version: 1744)
```

Both units are configured to the same channel (15) and same PAN id (0x1234). It's hooked to my machines [COM port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29) and can actually transmit data when I connect [picocom](http://linux.die.net/man/8/picocom) to it. (It responds to AT commands properly and can be configured fully through moltosenso Network Manager - I'm on a [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh)). All other registers are at their defaults, apart from the serial baudrate.

The XBee side source address is at 0x1, destination address is 0x2. Now when I type an [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character into picocom, this is what I see received on the other device, running in promiscous mode:

```
-- Typing "a"
E 61 88 7E 34 12 2 0 1 0 2B 0 61 E1
E 61 88 7E 34 12 2 0 1 0 2B 0 61 E1
E 61 88 7E 34 12 2 0 1 0 2B 0 61 E1
E 61 88 7E 34 12 2 0 1 0 2B 0 61 E1
-- Typing "b"
E 61 88 7F 34 12 2 0 1 0 2C 0 62 58
E 61 88 7F 34 12 2 0 1 0 2C 0 62 58
E 61 88 7F 34 12 2 0 1 0 2C 0 62 58
E 61 88 7F 34 12 2 0 1 0 2C 0 62 58
--- Typing "a" again
E 61 88 80 34 12 2 0 1 0 2D 0 61 A9
E 61 88 80 34 12 2 0 1 0 2D 0 61 A9
...
ln      pc pan   da  sa  ct   pl ck
```

So for every data payload sent, I see four frames sent out (nobody is picking them up of course). I suppose three of these are 802.15.4 retries, and XBee adds another one for kicks (although the RR register is clearly zero...).

What's the packet format here and where is this specified?

I've looked at XBee API packets and this does look *vaguely* similar, but I don't see 0x7e delimiters or anything like that here.

I guess what I am seeing is:

```
ln = length
61 = ??
88 = ??
pc = some sort of packet counter
pan = 16 bits of PAN ID
da = 16 bits of destination address
sa = 16 bits of source address
ct = another counter?
0 = ??
pl = my ASCII character payload
ck = probably a checksum
```

I tried with setting PAN to 0xFFFF and setting the destination address to 0xFF or broadcast, seeing pretty much the same. These 0x61 and 0x88 don't seem to correspond to much anything in the XBee documentation...

It doesn't directly look like 802.15.4 MAC level data frame either - or if it does, what are the missing fields and where are they specified? Pointers?

EDIT:
Actually, hmm. After importing a hex-formatted dump into [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark), it told me exactly that it's a 802.15.4 MAC frame and how to read it.

```
IEEE 802.15.4 Data, Dst: 0x0002, Src: 0x0001, Bad FCS
Frame Control Field: Data (0x8861)
.... .... .... .001 = Frame Type: Data (0x0001)
.... .... .... 0... = Security Enabled: False
.... .... ...0 .... = Frame Pending: False
.... .... ..1. .... = Acknowledge Request: True
.... .... .1.. .... = Intra-PAN: True
.... 10.. .... .... = Destination Addressing Mode: Short/16-bit (0x0002)
..00 .... .... .... = Frame Version: 0
10.. .... .... .... = Source Addressing Mode: Short/16-bit (0x0002)
Sequence Number: 126
Destination PAN: 0x1234
Destination: 0x0002
Source: 0x0001
```

I still don't know where the second 16-bit counter comes from in front of the actual data byte, and why FCS is messed up (I had to strip the beginning len field to get Wireshark to read it - that's probably it.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the second counter `ct` is a counter for the **application layer** in Zigbee protocol to notice when it should update its data because it is receiving a new one :) 
[image: APS Frame Format in Zigbee Protocol]

For more information about Frames Format in Zigbee Stack try to download this :
***[Newnes.ZigBee.Wireless.Networks.and.Transceivers.Sep.2008.eBook-DDU.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rx18xvkffndsmuu/Newnes.ZigBee.Wireless.Networks.and.Transceivers.Sep.2008.eBook-DDU_2.pdf?dl=0)***
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to read packets with X-CTU software?

I suggest you to read this post entry: http://www.tunnelsup.com/xbee-guide/

The pdf with the "Quick Reference Guide" is really useful and contains some data format indicated.

Also, it's always good to study the real documentation from developer (Digi in this case).

The frame is like:

[API Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyuad.jpg)

But only if you have configured previously the xbee to work in API mode with command:

```
ATAP 1
```

Or with XCTU.

Answer (score 0):

Try monitoring communication between two XBee modules to see what the acknowledgement frame looks like.

Try sending a sequence of bytes.

Try performing a Node Discovery (ATND) to see what those frames look like.

Try sending a remote AT command from X-CTU to see what those frames and responses look like.

When reverse engineering a protocol, it's useful to see both sides of the conversation.  You can test various theories by emulating each side of the protocol, and trying out variations on what you see.  For example, "What if I change this byte, does the remote end still respond?".

My guess is that you're correct about the `ct` byte being a counter.  The following zero byte could be flags, or it could identify the type of packet sent (serial data, remote AT command/response, node discovery/response, etc.).

As you build up an understanding of the structure, you can write a program to parse and dump the contents of the frames.  Dump an interpreted version of what you know, and leave the unknown bytes as a sequence of hex bytes.  Continue to experiment until you can narrow down the meaning of the remaining bytes.

Comment: Yes, except that while i can do reverse engineering and i know how to go about it, in this case i was looking for an actual specification or piece of documentation somewhere. Xbee should be a pretty well documented thing.

Comment: I don't believe Digi has documented details of their proprietary over-the-air data formats.

Answer (score 0):

The extra 2 bytes in payload (0x2D 0x0) is MaxStream header (MM in XCTU). If you disable the MaxStream headers by setting the MM command to *without* MaxStream headers, then these two bytes will become a part of a 802.15.4 payload, so your full payload would become 2B 0 61 instead of just 61